# Update chain of rows in which each row will affect next one through a computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

In a banking DB we want to hold the transactions and remainder amount of accounts after each transaction in a table named 'Operation' like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Operation (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Change int,
    PreviousId int null FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Operation(id),
    PreviousAmount int null,
    NewAmount AS (COALESCE(PreviousAmount,0) + Change) PERSISTED
);
```

(for simplicity I removed some columns like AccountId and Date)

PreviousId holds the id of last transaction of this account and will form a chain of transactions.

With this data:

```
INSERT INTO Operation (Id, Change, PreviousId, PreviousAmount)
VALUES
(1, 1, null, null),
(2, 2, 1, 1),
(3, 3, 2, 3),
(4, 4, 3, 5);
```

So far PreviousAmount and NewAmount has valid data:

```
id  change  previousId  previousAmount  newAmount
-------------------------------------------------
1   1       NULL        NULL            1
2   2       1           1               3
3   3       2           3               6
4   4       3           6               10
```

let's say we update first row "change":

```
Update Operation set Change=10 where id=1
```

I want a db level solution (like trigger) to update all PreviousAmount in the chain of rows so each row holds the updated "NewAmount" of previous row within its "PreviousAmount"

[Edit]

There is a solution to avoid computed column and compute NewAmount using window function in a trigger, but the reason I choose computed column is the reliability of validating non-negative newAmount.

using a window function requires that first an update take place and then another query update the newAmount column and see: if it's negative, rollback the transaction. but using a computed column and a db constraint there is no need for the second query and a transaction rollback as the db engine will do the magic.

Comment: I would urge you not to do this. Storing computed values is a nightmare. If you need to update a row in the middle you will have to recalculate every single row. What you are showing here looks an awful like maybe you should look into temporal tables instead.

Comment: @SeanLange based on my data pattern, chains are not so long and majority of updates are inserting new row to the end of the chain or creating new chains, but in few cases where a value is updated in the middle of the chain, I want to be sure there is no way my table hold invalid data. that's the reason of using computed column.

Comment: If the ID's are always in sequence then you could just calculate this when you need to the result, based on the data you showed where is just the sum of the change e.g. `SELECT *, SUM(Change) OVER() as NewAmount FROM myTable WHERE ID <= @myID`

Comment: @AlanSchofield in the main problem newAmount formula is more complex of that, but I may ended up using something like your approach (make the computed column a normal column and fill it within a trigger) if there is no way to utilize computed column for this problem

Comment: Doing this in a trigger is going down the path of total nightmare. That trigger is going to need some sort of iteration to update the entire chain. This likely means a cursor or some such ugliness. The performance is going to be terrible. Why not just use LEAD/LAG in your query when you pull the data and you need that value?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) to me. What are you actually doing with these values? You're storing a `change` but why calculate the running total _before_ you need to read it? Does it have to be stored as a chain? Could you use some sort of "set" identifier to group values and then use the `id` as the order? You would only need to calculate a running total when you read the values.

Comment: I see it's possible for values to be inserted into your chain, so what determines where in the chain they are put? If that information is available outside of the database why not store it _in_ the database and then there's no need for the `previousId`. Your data would be naturally ordered.

Comment: You said "I want to be sure there is no way my table hold invalid data" but as far as I can see the only columns which would end up with invalid data are the ones you're adding to try to prevent invalid data. If you were storing only the `change` and some way to order those changes what could go wrong?

Comment: @SeanLange that's the main point of this question, if there's a way (if possible a fast one) that sqlserver can handle this chain of updates so we can relay on sql server engine for always having valid data.

Comment: @tony "NewAmount" should be stored for reporting purposes and it's the column that may has wrong data if the chain is updated

Comment: If you only need `newAmount` in a report why not calculate it when it is read? That way the value is always correct. New inserts can happen at any time and you'll always get the correct total. If, as you say, "chains are not so long" the time taken to calculate the total will not be a problem

Comment: @tony there are many queries that need to read newAmount of some rows but don't need entire of the chain, there are also some other business rule on newAmount value that should be checked by DB (like not being negative)

Comment: "queries that need to read newAmount of some rows but don't need entire of the chain" - what information is used to select part of the chain? I'm asking because it's easy to calculate a running total of partial data if you know how it's selected. As for the `newAmount` not being negative, it will only be negative if you allow negative `change` values. Make the `change` column unsigned and you can never insert a negative number, no need to check.

Comment: It is "possible". But just because something can be done doesn't mean you should. The right way to do this would be to calculate the value when you retrieve the data..

Comment: I think the issue is that there is no simple way to calculate a cumulative value on the fly for a linked list. It is not as simple as an aggregate or windowed `SUM()` function. The only way I know how to do it ion a single statement is via a recursive CTE. The OP is making a design decision to trade a relatively complex  on-the-fly calculation with a calculate-once, store, and read-many approach. I can understand that - particularly if this is a "process setup" having many "operations", which changes infrequently, but is executed often.

Comment: @SeanLange you are right but I hope the are some db level solution to be relay on for having valid data in this problem so we could be sure bugs in the app would not create data inconsistency. I just edited the question and added more context to it.

Comment: @TN I just edited the question and added more context to it.

Comment: Thanks for adding some more information; you say it's a "banking DB ... to hold the transactions and reminder amount". If you are dealing with monetary transactions use double entry bookkeeping. I'm currently rewriting parts of a system which deals with money, it got in a mess because of _not_ using recognised accounting practices. Save yourself the pain of fixing this in the future by not inventing your own complex checking. BTW you wrote "transactions and reminder" but I think you mean _remainder_? (Amount left over after dividing one integer by another)

Comment: @tony thanks for your advice and you are right, I meant "remainder"

Comment: If these are banking transactions, will the **id** field always be ascending or is there some other *always-ascending* transaction identifier or timestamp field in your real data?  If so, I suggest that you **abandon the concept of a linked list (chain)** and only think of this data as a list *partitioned by* account number (or similar) and *ordered by* the ascending ID or timestamp. This then becomes the perfect fit for *window function* use. I will join the chorus and recommend that you drop the previousId and previousAmount and only calculate the running sum when needed as part of a query.

Comment: @TN then how the check that remainder amount does not become negative can be performed by db?

Comment: @HamedH - I think you need to update your question if the purpose is to calculate a running sum of both positive *and negative* changes, and then check to any negative running sums. That is not evident in your question. **Please clarify your end goal.** It can be done using window functions - something like `SUM(change) OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY id) AS CummulativeAmount` and then `WHERE CummulativeAmount < 0` or `MIN(CummulativeAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY account)` AS LowestCummulativeAmount`. To calculate the latter, you may need to wrap the first part into a subquery or CTE.

Comment: It may also help if you switch to real-world terms with less abstraction. Are these pending transactions (EFT, ACH, etc.) that have not yet been completed and finalized? Are these deposits where part or all of the amount is being held in a "not yet available for withdrawal" status (giving the deposited checks time to clear the issuing bank)? These concepts are not trade secrets, so I don't think you would get in trouble for discussing them.

Comment: @TN I just added the last [Edit] part to explain the reason of choosing computed column

Comment: So, from your latest edit, it sounds to me that **your end goal is to create a check constraint** that would prevent any insert or update that would allow the running sum to go negative at any point. Is that correct? For example, if you updated row id = 4 and set change = -5, that would be fine because the cumulative sum is still positive. But if you then updated row id = 3 and set change = 1, that would trigger check constraint error because although the cumulative sum for id = 3 is still positive, the cumulative sum for id = 4 now goes negative. Is that correct?

Comment: @TN yes that's the most important rule of the program. newAmount should not be negative at any time and I want this rule being applied in db level so app bugs or direct query run on db can not create data inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

*--- I will leave this up for now, not it appears from continued discussion that we are not actually dealing with a linked list, so the below may not be an appropriate solution. ---*

If after considering the advice from all of the comments above, you still prefer to store the running sums, this can be done with the help of a *recursive* Common Table Expression (CTE).

Given the id of the inserted or updated row, the CTE can follow the links down the chain and calculate the running totals along the way. This can then be fed into an `UPDATE` statement that applies the changes.

For repeated use, this could be wrapped up in a stored procedure. The following procedure will accept the id of the updated record or a NULL id to indicate that all values should be recalculated from the root (rows with previousId = NULL).

```
CREATE Procedure UpdateChain
    @StartingId INT
AS
    WITH CTE_Operation AS (
        -- Any root operation, when  @StartingId IS NULL
        SELECT
            O.*,
            previousAmountCalc = NULL,
            newAmountCalc = O.change
        FROM Operation O
        WHERE @StartingId IS NULL AND O.previousId IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        -- Specific operation row, when  @StartingId IS NOT NULL
        SELECT -- Initial explicitly selected operation
            O.*,
            previousAmountCalc = OP.newAmount,
            newAmountCalc = ISNULL(OP.newAmount, 0) + O.change
        FROM Operation O
        LEFT JOIN Operation OP ON OP.id = O.previousId
        WHERE O.id = @StartingId
        UNION ALL
        -- Recursively follow the links
        SELECT
            O.*,
            previousAmountCalc = C.newAmountCalc,
            newAmountCalc = C.newAmountCalc + O.change
        FROM CTE_Operation C
        JOIN Operation O ON O.previousId = C.id
    )
    UPDATE O
    SET
        previousAmount = previousAmountCalc,
        newAmount = newAmountCalc
    FROM CTE_Operation C
    JOIN Operation O ON O.id = C.id

-- End of procedure
```

It is worth noting that the above recursive CTE does not have any logic to detect cyclic (infinite loop) link arrangements and will error out if the number of recursions exceeds 100 (controlled by the `MAXRECURSION` option).

**Use case 1 - Initialization:**

```
INSERT Operation (id, change, previousId)
VALUES
    (1, 1, null),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 3, 2),
    (4, 4, 3)

-- Refresh all (starting with OPerations with previousId = NULL)
EXEC UpdateChain NULL
```

Results:

| id | change | previousId | previousAmount | newAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null | null | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 6 | 10 |

**Use case 2 - Updated row:**

```
UPDATE Operation
SET Change = 10
WHERE id = 1

-- Refresh everything from id = 1 and down the chain
EXEC UpdateChain 1
```

Results:

| id | change | previousId | previousAmount | newAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | null | null | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 10 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 12 | 15 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 15 | 19 |

**Use case 3 - Inserted row:**

```
-- Insert new operation after id = 2
INSERT Operation (id, change, previousId)
VALUES (5, 5, 2)

-- Adjust the backlink for the following operation to point to the new entry
UPDATE Operation
SET previousId = 5
WHERE id = 3

-- Refresh everything from the prior id = 2 and down the chain
EXEC UpdateChain 2
```

Results:

| id | change | previousId | previousAmount | newAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | null | null | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 10 | 12 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | 12 | 17 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | 17 | 20 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 20 | 24 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JPu8k_Gg) for a demonstration of the above.

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually this is similar to my plan b for this problem (not utilizing computed column) but I think if it's possible that we entrust calculations of newAmount to db engine using a computed column it would be a simpler and more robust solution

Answer (score 1):

*Update: See the trigger based solution at the end of this post*

First, your application business logic should be the first line of defense for enforcing data validity, database constraints should be used to enforce database integrity if the application fails to do its job.

I believe you can accomplish your integrity goals the implementing a table constraint that calls a function that validates the series of values for the current account. No extra columns are needed.

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ValidateOperationSeries (
    @AccountNo INT,
    @Change NUMERIC(19,2) -- Ignored, but must be present to catch column updates
) RETURNS BIT -- 1 = valid, 0 = invalid
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MinimumAmount NUMERIC(19,2) = (
        SELECT MIN(CummulativeAmount)
        FROM (
            SELECT SUM(O.Change) OVER(ORDER BY O.OperationId) AS CummulativeAmount
            FROM Operation O
            WHERE O.AccountNo = @AccountNo
        ) S
    )
             
    DECLARE @IsValid BIT = CASE WHEN @MinimumAmount < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

    RETURN @IsValid
END
```

Together with a table constraint:

```
    CONSTRAINT CK_Operation_ValidateOperationSeries
        CHECK (dbo.ValidateOperationSeries(AccountNo, Change) = 1)
```

This assumes that you have a column that unambiguously defines the row ordering
like **id** or some strictly ascending timestamp or transaction-number column. I also added an **AccountNo** column, to show how the constraint only considers the rows for the updated account.

Although the function does not directly use the **Change** parameter, it must be present in the check constraint expression to ensure that the constraint fires if that column is updated.

There are still a few logic gaps:

1. If a row is deleted, the check constraint will not execute.
2. If something else changes, like **AccountNo**, the check constraint may not revalidate all affected data.
   These cases could be left to the application to validate, but if really needed, triggers could still be implemented to call the validation function and take appropriate action if needed.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bLje--8u) for a demo that includes insert and update actions with a mix of pass and fail scenarios.

**ADDENDUM:**

Perhaps a cleaner solution that should catch all cases would be a trigger that identifies and validates all affected accounts.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Operation_ValidateOperationSeries
    ON Operation 
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @FailedAccountNo INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 A.AccountNo
        FROM (
            -- Get affected account numbers where some key data has changed
            SELECT DISTINCT A.AccountNo
            FROM INSERTED I
            FULL OUTER JOIN DELETED D ON D.OperationId = I.OperationId
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT I.AccountNo WHERE I.AccountNo IS NOT NULL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT D.AccountNo WHERE D.AccountNo IS NOT NULL
            ) A
            WHERE (
                D.OperationId IS NULL    -- Any inserted row
                OR I.OperationId IS NULL -- Any deleted row
                OR UPDATE(AccountNo)     -- PARTITION BY key changed
                OR UPDATE(OperationId)   -- The ORDER BY column changed
                OR UPDATE(Change)        -- Tracked value changed
            )
        ) A
        WHERE dbo.ValidateOperationSeries(A.AccountNo) = 0 -- Validation Fails
    )

    IF @FailedAccountNo IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(1000) =
            CONCAT('Operation series failed validation for account ',
                    @FailedAccountNo,
                   ' in TR_Operation_ValidateOperationSeries.');
        THROW 50000, @ErrorMessage, 1
    END
```

The above will extract all affected accounts and call the previously defined validation function. (This time the extra @Change parameter is eliminated.) Affected accounts include those from any inserted or deleted rows, rows where the Change column is updated, and both the before and after values if the AccountNo column changes.

For updates, account (re-)validation will only be performed is one of the key columns is changed. The above trigger must be set up to recognize any columns that affect the f=validation results. These include:

- The PARTITION BY column - AccountNo in the test scenario
- The ORDER BY column - OperationId in the test scenario, but will likely be a different timestamp or other strictly ascending transaction number of some type.
- The data being tracked - Change in the test scenario

See [this db<>query](https://dbfiddle.uk/SwHH13ls) for the trigger-based demo.

Comment: Thank you so much. this will solve my problem and also gave me some new ideas about other parts. ❤️

Comment: Update: See the trigger based solution at the end of the above post.

Comment: More tweaks and added test steps. Added notes regarding proper coding of the `UPDATE(column-name)` conditions in the trigger to both ensure that (1) all cases are covered, and (2) avoiding unnecessary checks.  Also improved the error message to include the offending account number. See the edit history.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I got it right, can the "outer apply" be replaced by a cross apply?

Comment: Yes. The OUTER APPLY is like a LEFT JOIN, while CROSS APPLY is like an INNER JOIN. In this case CROSS APPLY would be better, since we don't need the LEFT JOIN behavior.  Thanks for pointing this out. I'll update the answer.